# Presta shop duplicate action in custom module not working

Tags: model-view-controller, prestashop-1.6

I am working on a presta shop 1.6/30bees module which has a list view in the backend. 'Edit' and 'Delete' actions are set up and work as expected, however when I use `addRowAction('duplicate')` to add the duplicate action, I do get a link without the right parameters.

The button is rendered, but the link leaves out the item id and the action name. I thought duplicate is a default action that needs little to no work, however I also do find little documentation on that one.

My module currently extends AdminController, but extending ModuleAdminController did not change the outcome either.

```
public function renderList() {
    // add edit function to list item
    $this->addRowAction('edit');

    // add duplication function to list item
    $this->addRowAction('duplicate');

    // add delete function to list item
    $this->addRowAction('delete');

    return parent::renderList();
}
```

Am I missing a detail on how to get duplicate to work or am I in the wrong and have to add it like a full custom action?

Comment: Afaik only view, edit, details and delete are default row actions.

Comment: @TheDrot I have been looking up things in the code. The duplicate action is listed as default action in the AdminControllerCore, there are helper functions to render the duplicate button, too, including a confirm_link javascript that I'd rather not have there. But it looks like no actual duplicate action was implemented. It looks like it has been attempted to add it, but never was completed.

Comment: I digged into the code and you're right it's there. However it looks as you said it has no default implementation. The button will render with some javascript popup asking you if you want to copy images or not and then it will make an ajax call with the id and action and you have to return URL so it redirects or refreshes the page. Looks like the action was made for duplicating products as `AdminProductsController` has the action defined. You'll have to make your own action and you can also define your own render button action in your controller with the required params.